# Select box menu not working on mouse click in Firefox version 58

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, cross-browser

I am having a select box menu and its not working on mouse click in Firefox 58.
But in previous version its worked fine. Also its working fine in other browsers too. My code looks like this:

```
<div class="custom-select custom-select-result custom-select-sort data-filter">
            <select id="sort-select-1">
                <option value="lowtohigh">Price (Low-High)</option>
                <option value="hightolow">Price (High-Low)</option>
                <option value="brand">Brand</option>
                <option value="mileage">Mileage Warranty</option>
                <option value="wet">Wet</option>
                <option value="dry">Dry</option>
                <option value="comfort">Comfort</option>
                <option value="winter">Winter/Snow</option>
                <option value="tread">Treadwear</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .top-result-container .custom-select-result.custom-select-sort {
        background-position: 95% 15%;
        padding-right: 11px;
    }

    .top-result-container .custom-select-result {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 25px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        border: 0;
        position: relative;
        overflow: visible;
    }

.custom-select {
    padding: 0 0 1px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('');
}
```

Added JS:

```
$(".custom-select-result").click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).hasClass('custom-selected')){
        $(".filter-details").hide();
        $(".custom-select-result").removeClass("custom-bg custom-selected");
    }else{
        $('.data-filter .filter-details').hide();
        $('.custom-select-result').removeClass("custom-bg custom-selected");
        $(this).addClass("custom-bg custom-selected data-filter");
        $(this).children().show();
    }
    if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
        $('body').addClass('results-grid-filter-active');
    }

});
```

Please check the above JS code. I have used click event and this code working fine in chrome not in firefox.

Comment: Don't see any reason for this not to work.. there might be some JS error. Did you check console for any errors?

Comment: Checked there is no console error.

Comment: I am having one parent div for this select.

Comment: Share the entire HTML and relevant JS. Bcz this code is working properly without any errors.

Comment: @MilanChheda Shared js code